# Code to run module from a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble running my mammoth code through a command button, so it got me thinking is there a way to call out a module and run it through a command button, rather than have the actual code embedded into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code in a standard module and then right-click the button and assign the code to it

[image].